# How do I remove a list element from an unordered list?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a scrollable message log to record the event history of a turn based fighting game, but I don't want the message log to span more than 10 messages. However for some reason, it won't remove the 0th list element from the list (whenever the count reaches over 10) after calling the function multiple times. It instead keeps stacking them on the bottom of the list, extending the scrolling menu to an unreasonable length. I have many questions:

1. How would I fix this/is there an alternative way to remove list
   elements from an unordered list... I suspect it may be because I've
   put the list inside the "nav" tag..
2. Is there an alternative for creating a scrollable message log?
3. Is there a way for this scrolling message log to place the new
           entires at the top, so that it pushes the history out of sight, as
           oppose to putting the new entires at the bottom of the list (out of
           sight, unless the user scrolls down)?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul id="battleLog"></ul>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
function updateBattleLog(x) {
    var count = count+1;
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(x);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("battleLog").appendChild(node);



    if (count > 10) {
        var list = document.getElementById("battleLog");
        list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
        count = count-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var count = count+1;` should throw an error...

Comment: @evolutionxbox, It won't throw because `var count` is hoisted. The actual expression would evaluate to `undefined + 1` which is `NaN`

Comment: Ah right... I tested using a return which caused the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `count` variable is locally scoped and you're re-initializing it to `1` on every call to the function (hence it will never reach your `10` limit).

Try this instead:

```
var count = 0;

function updateBattleLog(x) {
    count++;

    // ...
}
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3opp4cro/)

Comment: Wow thanks- it works! Haha I feel pretty dumb now about missing that!